# AppBrain offers to update app that marketplace does not

Tags: htc-sense, google-play-store, updates, app-brain

The Appbrain app is offering to update my Maps, Street View and Facebook app. In the Android Marketplace, I can't see any option to update (though I have never updated an app before so I don't know how the update would appear). I am wondering if this difference has something to do with HTC customisations. Should I allow Appbrain to update these applications or not?

Comment: What version of the apps are you running and what version is appbrain trying to update you to?

Comment: I have maps 4126, street view 1506 and Facebook 121. On AppBrains, I am not sure what it was offering to update me to, but the latest version are Google Maps 4.5.1, street view 1.6.0.6 and Facebook 1.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Were these pre-installed apps? You won't get market update notificatins for apps that are pre-installed, you have to go to the market and manually install any newer versions of the app and then you'll get future updates via the market.

The same thing happened with my Droid.  I heard about an update for Facebook (which came on my phone), but never saw an update in the market until I searched for it and manually installed the app.

Comment: They were preinstalled. So is it safe to upgrade them? Could it break HTC sense in any way?

Comment: @Casebash you should be good to update :)

Comment: Don't seem to have any problems after upgrading, will update if I do

Comment: I noticed the same thing when I got appbrain... I don't understand the logic but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases AppBrain does not check app compatibility restrictions correctly when deciding to offer the update. E.g., I have Android 4.0.4 (CM9) with the [Google Search](http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-search/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) app version 1.4.1.299849 installed as a system app (included in `gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip`). AppBrain shows that an update (version 2.6.7.721924arm)  is available for this app, but when I attempt to install the update, Play Market shows “Not supported on your device”, because apparently all versions of this app offered on Google Play require Android >= 4.1.